# Sympy latex export using python

Tags: python, latex, sympy

I am trying to use the following python code

Solved (Hint by @TheFool): By putting latex() into the print function it works.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.printing.mathml import mathml
init_printing(use_unicode=True) # allow LaTeX printing

# independent variables
x, y, z = symbols('x y z', real = True)

# parameters
nu, rho = symbols('nu rho', real = True, constant = True, positive = True)

# dependent variables
u, v, w = symbols('u v w', real = True, cls = Function)

print(latex(diff(u(x,y,z),x)))
```

The output looks like 
`'\\frac{\\partial}{\\partial x} u{\\left (x,y,z \\right )}'`.

How can I remove the additional backslashes and the quotation marks at the beginning and at the end of the output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried to include:.. ?

```
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing()
```

check out the ducumentation on sympy`s print options. It looks like the init_printing is the way to go for proper output.

http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/printing.html

Comment: plus one: Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 8):

```
from sympy import Matrix, print_latex

X = Matrix([1,2,3])
print_latex(X)
```

`out: \left[\begin{matrix}1\\2\\3\end{matrix}\right]`

(only prints out like that if your in a notebook environment)

Answer (score 1):

When you write the output on a file with

```
out_file = open("output.txt","w")
out_file.write(latex(diff(u(x,y,z),x)))
out_file.close()
```

They will look like you want them.